# How to split and reorder the content inside the ((PERS)) tag by ' y ' or ' y)' using Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, split

```py
import re

input_text = "((PERS) Marcos Sy y) ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds" #example 1
input_text = "ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas" #example 2

input_text = re.sub(
                    r"\(\(PERS\)" + r"((?:\w\s*)+(?:\sy\s(?:\w\s*)+)+)(?=\s*y\s*(?:\)|\())",
                    #lambda m: (f"((PERS)){m[1]}) y"),
                    lambda m: (f"((PERS)){m[1].replace(' y', ') y ((PERS)')}"),
                    input_text, re.IGNORECASE)

print(input_text) # --> output
```

I need to separate the content inside a `((PERS) )` tag if there is a `" y "` or a `" y)"` in between.
So get the `" y"` or the `" y "` out of the `((PERS) )` tag and the rest of the content (in case it finds as is the case in `example 2`) left in another `((PERS) )` tag. I try with `\s+y\s+?` and with `\s+y\s+`

To achieve the desired output, I tried with a regex to match all the names inside the `((PERS) )` tag that are separated by `" y "` or `" y)"`. For that I tried to use a positive lookahead to check for `" y "` or `" y)"` after each name, and then group all the names together. But this lookahead dont works well.

So get this output for each of the examples respectively

```
"((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds" #for example 1

"ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS)Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas" #for example 2
```

This regex is for content that does or does have to start with a capital letter `r"([A-Z][\wí]+\s*)"` although I think that in this case it would be better to simply use `r"((?:\w\s*)+)"` since the content is already encapsulated.

Comment: I've noticed a number of questions about processing text like this. Is this a standard format for NLP? Maybe there's a library for parsing it so you don't have to roll your own with regular expressions.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried many libraries to build, but unfortunately in Spanish there are not as many as in English. So I started building my own information recognition library for future use in various data analysis projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use 2 regexes which simplifies it a lot. First:

```
input_text = re.sub(
  r"\(\(PERS\)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+y\)\s+\(\(PERS\)\s+([\w\s]+)\)",
  lambda m: (f"((PERS) {m[1]}) y ((PERS) {m[2]})"),
  input_text,
  re.IGNORECASE)
```

This one covers your 1st use case and matches:

- `((PERS)`
- followed by some whitespace `\s+`
- some mixed word characters and whitespaces that get captured `([\w\s]+)`, as I understand without any other characters like `-`
- some more whitespaces until `y)`
- then again the same except without `y`: `\(\(PERS\)\s+([\w\s]+)\)`
  Then we format both matched groups into `((PERS) {m[1]}) y ((PERS) {m[2]})` format.

The 2nd part of solution is very similar, except it just matches the 2nd group inside the 1st parentheses:

```
input_text = re.sub(
  r"\(\(PERS\)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+y\s+([\w\s]+)\)",
  lambda m: (f"((PERS) {m[1]}) y ((PERS) {m[2]})"),
  input_text,
  re.IGNORECASE)
```

You could ofc do it with a much more convoluted regex and replacement lambda, but I see no point. This regex would work, for instance:
`\(\(PERS\)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+(y|y\s+([\w\s]+))\)(\s+\(\(PERS\)\s+([\w\s]+)\))?` but then you'd need to cover for cases when there's group 1 and group 5 or otherwise use logic for group 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, two separated regex would be simplier and clearer. Tests: [simple](https://regex101.com/r/SFi2A7/1), then [expanded](https://regex101.com/r/aA60Uz/1) (with [partial](https://regex101.com/r/EBWKNr/1)).
Example 1 seems to be a bug, while example 2 needs to be splitted:

```
input_text = ''
input_text += "((PERS) Marcos Sy y) ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds" #example 1
input_text += "\n"
input_text += "ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas" #example 2

input_text += "\n\n" \
    + "((PERS) Marcos Sy y) ((PERS) Lucy) ((PERS) Marcos Sy y Ana) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds\n\
ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Isabel y Ana y Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas"
    # example 1+2 expanded


import re

# first: for example 2

# # for example 2 expanded
input_text = re.sub(
    r"\(\(PERS\)    (?P<multiple>    (?:  (?: \s [A-Zí][\wí]+(?:\s[a-zí]+)? )* \sy  )+    (?:\s[^\)]+)    )    \)",
    lambda m: (f"((PERS){m['multiple'].replace(' y', ') y ((PERS)')})"),
    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE # re.VERBOSE == re.X # extended (ignore white space)
)

# # for example 2 (simple)
# input_text = re.sub( \
#     r'(\(\(PERS\)(?:\s(?!y)(?:[\wí]+))*)\sy(\s[A-Zí][\wí]+(?:\s[a-zí]+)?\))', \
#     r'\g<1>) y ((PERS)\g<2>', \
#     input_text, \
#     flags = re.MULTILINE)

# second: for example 1

input_text = re.sub( \
    r'(\(\(PERS\)(?:\s(?:[\wí]+))*)\sy\)', \
    r'\1) y', \
    input_text, \
    flags = re.MULTILINE)

print(input_text)
```

result (original examples 1+2):

```
"((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds"
"ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS) Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas"
```

result (expanded example 1+2):

```
"((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Lucy) ((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Ana) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds"
"ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS) Isabel) y ((PERS) Ana) y ((PERS) Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas"
```

(Are you sure expecting `((PERS)Rosa ds)` - without space? And it's no clear you need "ds" after "Rosa"? I don't speak Spanish, maybe that? ;) but dealt with it :) )

Answer (score 1):

If there can not be any other occurrence of a parenthesis, you might use a pattern with 2 capture groups, and then use split on the second group to get the separate parts between  `y` so that there can also be multiple names.

Pattern to get the `((PERS)...)` parts with  `y`

```
(\(\(PERS\)\s*)((?:(?![()]|\sy\b).)* y\b[^()]*?)\s*\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I7qjXc/1)

After these replacements, you can put  `y`  between all the remaining consecutive `((PERS)...)` parts with another pattern:

```
(\(\(PERS\)[^()]*\))\s*(?=\(\(PERS\)[^()]*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3RG20o/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(\(\(PERS\)\s*)((?:(?![()]|\sy\b).)* y\b[^()]*?)\s*\)"
s = ("((PERS) Marcos Sy y) ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds\n"
            "ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas\n"
            "ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María y Rosa ds y Test Person 1 y test person 2) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas")


def custom_replacement(m):
    return m.group(1) + " y ((PERS) ".join([p + ")" for p in re.split(r"\s+y\b\s*", m.group(2)) if p])


replaced_names = re.sub(pattern, custom_replacement, s)
replaced_pers = re.sub(r"(\(\(PERS\)[^()]*\))\s*(?=\(\(PERS\)[^()]*\))", r"\1 y ", replaced_names)
print(replaced_pers)
```

Output

```
((PERS) Marcos Sy) y ((PERS) Lucy) estuvieron ((VERB) jugando) sdds
ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS) Rosa ds) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas
ashsahghgsa ((PERS) María) y ((PERS) Rosa ds) y ((PERS) Test Person 1) y ((PERS) test person 2) son alumnas de esa escuela y juegan juntas
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/t3c7WN).